# How to create a whitelist of network accessing apps(i.e block everything except firefox)

Tags: networking

Before all, I know its a duplicate. I asked because the other answers were not satisfactory or didn't exactly match my needs, so don't flag it right away as duplicate :)

Now, the question is pretty straightforward, I want to block, literally ERVERYTHING, except Firefox. The reason is I am on an Internet with a monthly quota of 500MB, so I don't want the background processes suck that precious bytes.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try a firewall service...

Comment: firewalls dont work at application aka package level. Can you give more instructions on how to do this?